# new find view is being processed as new create request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had a question earlier on this, I am trying to make a ldap search form. 
So far I did rails generate for users/find. In the model I have a function to search a user in ldap, which works fine independently outside of rails. 
but the request through this view is actually getting treated as a request to create a new user, instead to just search the user in ldap. 
I am new to rails, dont what the missing link is. Need some help here understanding this, in future there will be a lot of functions/features like this I have to add in this test app. Which I think will probably lead to the same issue.

```
# rails generate controller users find
```

error -

```
undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
Started GET "/users/find" for 10.85.41.23 at 2012-04-05 19:56:27 -0400
Processing by UsersController#find as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/user.rb:54:in `FindActiveDirectory'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `find'
```

Model -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :role, :misc, :password

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :role, :on => :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :email

  ROLES = ['Admin','User']

####################
  SERVER = '10.10.10.1'   
  PORT = 389                    
  BASE = 'DC=User,DC=mysite,DC=com'   
  DOMAIN = 'ldap.mysite.com'       
####################

  def self.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticate(login, pass)
     user = find_by_user_id(login)

     if user
     nil
     else
     return false
     end
        conn = Net::LDAP.new :host => SERVER,
                         :port => PORT,
                         :base => BASE,
                         :auth => { :username => "#{login}@#{DOMAIN}",
                                    :password => pass,
                                    :method => :simple }
        if conn.bind
        return user
        else
        return false
        end
        rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError => e
        return false
end

  def self.FindActiveDirectory(login)
        conn = Net::LDAP.new :host => SERVER,
                         :port => PORT,
                         :base => BASE,
                         :auth => { :username => 'admin',
                                    :password => 'adminpass',
                                    :method => :simple }

if  conn.bind
        conn.search(:base => BASE, :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "sAMAccountName", login ),
        :attributes => ['givenName','SN','mail'], :return_result => true) do |entry|
        entry.each do |attributes, values|

        if "#{attributes}" == "sn"
        values.each do |value|
        puts "Lastname: "+"#{value}"
        $lastname = "#{value}"
        end
        end

        if "#{attributes}" == "givenname"
        values.each do |value|
        puts "Firstname: "+"#{value}"
        $firstname = "#{value}"
        end
        end

        if "#{attributes}" == "mail"
        values.each do |value|
        puts "Email: "+"#{value}"
        $email = "#{value}"
        end
        end

        end
        end

    return true
    else
    return false
    end

    rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError => e
    return false
   end

end
```

controller -

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def new
        @user = User.new
  end


  def find
   @user = User.FindActiveDirectory(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user_id])
        if @user.save
                redirect_to users_added_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
        else
                render "new"
        end
  end

end
```

View -

```
<h1>Users#find</h1>
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :Username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

routes -

```
rubyapp::Application.routes.draw do

  get "users/find"

get "myapp/new"

root :to => "sessions#new"
#root :to => "home#index"
get "sessions/new"
get "users/new"
get "users/added" => "users#added"
get "myapp" => "myapp#new"
get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"

resources :users
resources :sessions
 end
```

Comment: Mhh as far as i know are methods supposed to start with a small letter - so change the name to `findActiveDirectory`.
And could you post your entire user model? The errors occures on line 54 in the user model - but you posted only 50 lines...

Comment: @klump - I edited my code to add full user model. the line number probably won't be exact since here I tried remove blank/comment lines.

Comment: @klump - `app/models/user.rb:54:in `FindActiveDirectory'
` Here the error line is 54, which is `conn.search(:base => BASE, :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "sAMAccountName", login ),`. For `app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `find'` is `@user = User.FindActiveDirectory(params[:user_id])
`.

Comment: Do you pass the `user_id` into the controller via the url? If you do so, how does your url look like? Could you post the entry in the `config/routes.rb` file?

Comment: @klump - I access it directly in url as /users/find. It brings up a small html form of a text_field and a submit button. My routes say - ` users_find GET    /users/find(.:format)        users#find
`

Comment: @klump - Edited my question to add full routes. thanks for helping out.

Comment: The routes seem fine. Do you have to require something for being able to do all the LDAP stuff? I do not see any require statements in the model, where do you do that?

Comment: I require net-ldap which I have in Gemfile `gem 'net-ldap'`. There is nothing more at all in the app other than ldap authentication and ldap search, so no other code is needed.

Comment: ldap authentication is working, but not search.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9761/discussion-between-firstname-lastname-and-klump)

Comment: @klump - Hey.. thanks a LOT man. I got it working today. I used your code and did some small adjustments, it worked! I learned some basic stuff from your code to build new things on. If I get stuck, I am gonna bug you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another method to handle the data you returned:

the controller:

```
def find
end

def display_result
  @result = User.findActiveDirectory( params[:user_id] )

  if @result.empty?
    render action: "find", notice: "Could not find a user with id #{params[:user_id]}"
  end
end
```

next step is to add a route to the routes.rb:

```
get 'users/find'
post 'users/display_result'
```

now we have to update the view for find:

```
<h1>Users#find</h1>

<p><%= notice %></p>

<%= form_tag users_display_result_path do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :Username %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :user_id %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= submit_tag %></p>
<% end %>
```

and create the new view for displaying the result (this one is very basic, i guess you need to improve this a lot, but this should give you an idea):

```
<h1>Users#display_result</h1>
<%= debug @result %>
```

and last but not least change some stuff in the model:

```
def self.FindActiveDirectory(login)
  conn = Net::LDAP.new :host => SERVER,
                       :port => PORT,
                       :base => BASE,
                       :auth => { :username => 'admin',
                                  :password => 'adminpass',
                                  :method => :simple }

  if  conn.bind
    result = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new

    conn.search( :base => BASE,
                 :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "sAMAccountName", login ),
                 :attributes => ['givenName','SN','mail'],
                 :return_result => true
    ) do |entries|

      entries.each do |attribute, value|
        result[attribute] = value
      end
  end

  return result

  rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError => e
    return false
end
```

You will end up in the controller/ view with a variable called @result. This variable is a hash with the attributes as key. So you could do something like this in the view:

```
<% @result.each do |key,value| %>
  <%= key.to_s.normalize + ": " + value.to_s %>
<% end >
```